# Issues with multiple SELECT statement

Tags: php, sql, select, syntax, where-clause

Hi guys i'm currently working through a road side defect project and have hit a wall in my research. 
I am trying to select a number of values from different tables with the sql code as

```
$sql = "SELECT d.defect_Id, d.priority, r.date 
        FROM `defect_report` AS d, 
        `report` AS r
        WHERE d.report_Id = r.report_Id";
```

This code selects the values I need below:

```
defect_Id | priority | date
64           1         2016-01-06 19:17:40
65           3         2016-01-06 19:17:47
81           2         2016-01-06 19:17:47
82           1         2016-01-06 19:17:47
83           1         2016-01-06 19:17:47
66           3         2016-01-06 19:18:30
67           5         2016-01-06 19:18:37
68           4         2016-01-06 19:18:43
69           1         2016-01-06 19:18:49
```

However when I assign a Job I want the table above to only show unassigned jobs.  The form I use displays just one job at a time and allows me to submit a repair team to a job assigning it a job number in the job table and issuing a timestamp.

For example once submitted defect 64 will have a assigned to a team in the job table. How do I add to below code so this defect dose not show again when the page redirects.

```
foreach ($cxn->query($sql) as $row )  
{
    echo "<tr><td><input type='text' name='defect_Id' value='$row[defect_Id]'</td>";
    echo "<td>$row[priority]</td>";
    echo "<td>$row[date]</td></tr>";
}
echo"</table>";
```

I have tried a number of options but my syntax is wrong. In effect this below is what im trying to achieve 2 WHERE clauses in one sql statement is this possible?

```
$sql = "SELECT d.`defect_Id`,d.`priority`, r.`date`
        FROM `defect_report` AS d, `report` AS r
        WHERE r.`report_Id` = d.`report_ID`
        OR
        WHERE NOT EXISTS 
        (                         
        SELECT  `defect_Id`
        FROM job AS j
        WHERE d.`defect_Id` = j.`defect_Id` )";
```

In the Job table the Primary key is `job_Id` 
with indexes of `defect_Id` & `repair_Team`

In the `defect_report` table the primary  key is `defect_Id` with `report_Id` as index

In the report table the primary key is `report_Id` with index of `member_Id` from the person reporting it.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: That is rather a lot of code to plough through. Can you not reduce it to the key parts

Comment: Also tag dbms uses. (Some non-ANSI SQL there...)

Comment: Also one of those fragments of code, after this `Once submitted defect 64 will have a assigned` is messed up PHP tag wise

Comment: It was a mistake that had slipped through

Comment: I want to make sure I'm understanding this right.  Is the query you're looking for is supposed to be returning records from `defect_report` that have not yet been assigned a repair team?

Comment: The query is getting the values defect_id & priority from the defect_report table & date from the report table where a job number has not been assigned

Comment: Answer below @trincot

Comment: Edited code to avoid duplicate and improve indentation

Answer (score 0):

You use the `WHERE` clause for join conditions. Although that works, more complex queries are more readable when you use the `JOIN` clause.

Add the Job table to your query like this:

```sql
SELECT d.`defect_Id`, r.`date`, d.`priority` 
FROM `defect_report` AS d 
JOIN `report` AS r 
ON r.`report_Id` = d.`report_ID` 
LEFT JOIN `job` AS j ON d.`defect_Id` = j.`defect_Id` 
WHERE j.`defect_Id` IS NULL
```

The `LEFT` keyword makes sure you get also those records that have no corresponding Job record. And the `WHERE` clause then throws away the cases where there was a matching Job record, leaving you with the result you are interested in.

Comment: Above edited query works great you have saved me a great deal of stress many thanks all!

Comment: You're welcome. Note that you don't need the back ticks, only when you have used a reserved word or space or non-standard symbol in your column name. I personally think they look ugly, so I try to avoid them where possible.